# react native cron job lib

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I am working on a react-native based mobile app using expo.

in the app the user can set schedules for medication reminders, for that I am using `expo-notifications` to show those reminders.

`expo-notifications` provides some functions to schedule notifications, but it is not that flexible.

schedules like every Sunday at 09:00am, or every 2 days at 05:00pm, daily at 08:30pm, and so on...

I need a library that helps in scheduling those reminder notifications, with the **ability to cancel** the scheduled notification.

My important thing is that the suggested library should work even if **the app is backgrounded or killed**.

Any other suggestions on how to make reminders that work even if the app is backgrounded or killed are appreciated.

I tried `node-schedule` but I found it works only if the app is in foreground.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for a more robust reminder scheduler solution? I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out react-native-background-timer: https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer